# Parsing Docker image tag into component parts

Tags: docker, docker-registry

A canonical Docker image tag is in the form:

```
[[registry-address]:port/]name:tag
```

The address and port can be omitted, in which case Docker goes to the default registry which is the Docker Hub. For example the following are all valid:

```
ubuntu:latest
nixos/nix:1.10
localhost:5000/myfirstimage:latest
localhost:5000/nixos/nix:latest
```

I need some code that will parse this string reliably into its component parts. However it seems impossible to do this unambiguously because the "name" component can contain a slash. For example the following tag is ambiguous:

```
localhost/myfirstimage:latest
```

This could be an image with name `localhost/myfirstimage` on the Docker Hub, or it could be an image with the name `myfirstimage` on the registry running at address `localhost`.

Does anybody know how Docker itself parses such input?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37861791/596285) may be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it can be parsed unambiguously indeed.

According to [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1453)

> current syntax for identifying an image is something like this:
>
> [registry_hostname[:port]/][user_name/]( repository_name[:version_tag] | image_id )
>
> ...
>
> localhost is the only single-name host allowed. All others must contain either a port (":") or multiple parts ("foo.bar", so containing a ".")

In practice that means that if you docker image identifier starts with *localhost*, it will be resolved against the registry running at *localhost:80*

```bash
>docker pull localhost/myfirstimage:latest
Pulling repository localhost/myfirstimage
Error while pulling image: Get http://localhost/v1/repositories/myfirstimage/images: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: getsockopt: connection refused
```

(tested with Docker 1.12.0)

the same for *"."*

```bash
>docker pull a.myfirstimage/name:latest
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://a.myfirstimage/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup a.myfirstimage on 127.0.0.1:53: no such host
```

and *":"*

```bash
>docker pull myfirstimage:80/name:latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://myfirstimage:80/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup myfirstimage on 127.0.0.1:53: no such host
```

So your parsing code should look at the substring before the first *"/"*, and check if it is *"localhost"*, or it contains *"."* or ends with *":XYZ"* (a port number), in which case it is a *registry_hostname*, otherwise it is a *repository name* (username/repository_name).

The Docker code which implements this, seem to be located here:
[reference.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/vendor/github.com/docker/distribution/reference/reference.go) and [service.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/registry/service.go)

```go
// splitReposSearchTerm breaks a search term into an index name and remote name
func splitReposSearchTerm(reposName string) (string, string) {
        nameParts := strings.SplitN(reposName, "/", 2)
        var indexName, remoteName string
        if len(nameParts) == 1 || (!strings.Contains(nameParts[0], ".") &&
                !strings.Contains(nameParts[0], ":") && nameParts[0] != "localhost") {
                // This is a Docker Index repos (ex: samalba/hipache or ubuntu)
                // 'docker.io'
                indexName = IndexName
                remoteName = reposName
        } else {
                indexName = nameParts[0]
                remoteName = nameParts[1]
        }
        return indexName, remoteName
}
```

(though I've not investigated it in more details)