# How does Docker push detemines which part of the path is the host

Tags: docker

Newbie with docker, i feel i am missing some concept...

As far as can tell we can tag (confusing double meaning, but well...) then push an image with:

docker push aaa.bbb.com/some_folder/another.folder/name:version

how does docker now that aaa.bbb.com is a host or simply part of the repository name ?
In other words the repository can be 'aaa.bbb.com/some_folder/another.folder/name' or 'some_folder/another.folder/name' in the aaa.bbb.com registry

When i dont use a :PORT how does docker know which one ? does it try to resolve the first portion and if found assume being a registry server ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37861791/596285

Answer (score 1):

When you use a Docker image name, such as aaa.bbb.com/some_folder/another.folder/name:version, Docker interprets the first part of the image name (aaa.bbb.com) as the registry host if it contains a dot ( .), colon ( :) or localhost.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but this answer would greatly benefit from supporting information (links or citations needed)

Comment: I had already read that page. And it is precisely the fact that path separator can contain dots that confuses me. Besides I can have a host without the port and without dots if i am resolving it with hosts file for example. I can accept that being required to use :PORT do disambiguate could work

Comment: I guess that a good strategy, to be on the safe side, is to specify the PORT even when it is the default 443